# A property of limits and inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis

I have just finished some analysis which seems to rely on the property that if $ 0 < x \leq a$ then, as a tends to zero, x will tend to a. Is this a valid property? I was wondering if there might a formal proof of the property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does is matter that I have $\alpha < \beta \leq \gamma$ rather than $\alpha \leq \beta \leq \gamma$ ? This is still the same person, I'm having trouble commenting on answers for some reason...

Comment: Have you tried to prove it using, say, $\epsilon$-$\delta$?

Comment: It doesn't. When taking limits, $<$ becomes $\leq$ as the example $\{1/n\}_n$ shows.

Comment: Your account got "split", this is due to your account being "unregistered", in which case the website tries to remember who you are based on some cookies/ip-address/etc magic which is very, very fragile and fails easily. Please register your account. Afterward you should visit [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) to request your two user profiles be merged. Be sure to include a link to both [this profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/110432/pete) and [this profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/110436/pete).

Answer (score 0):

It is the comparison theorem: if $\alpha \leq \beta \leq \gamma$ and $\lim \alpha = \lim \gamma=\ell$, then also $\lim \beta =\ell$.